# SQL Server edition for BI developers - Complete BI suite

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-data-tools, powerbi, msbi

I don't know whether this questions stands correctly or not for Stack.

I am a MSBI developer working with the SQL Server Enterprise edition, but newbie to SQL Server editions...

I would like to know which edition of the SQL Server can I install at my home desktop, which is bundled with complete MSBI Suite features.

Thanks,

Comment: `Developer edition + SSDT`

Comment: @Devart, seems it have some compatibility issues. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a9da27b3-714a-463e-a9b0-7617a4ec2f36/ssdt-or-bids-not-available-with-sql-server-2014-developer-edition?forum=ssdt

Comment: Reading information under link you provided it looks like it's compatibility issue with VS Express. As far as I remember VS Express wasn't capable of using plugins. I'm using MSSQL 2012 dev edition + SSDT + SSDTBI + BIDS Helper with Visual Studio Premium 2012 without any issues.

Comment: Look here, it's from 2014 but I couldn't find that they changed anything: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx

Comment: if we buy developer edition and install visual studio 2015 community edition,do we still need to buy BI tools (ssdt) or do we get full features of ssrs and ssis

Comment: I'd definitely look at Developer edition - it's a full copy of SQL Server w/ all tools for ~ USD 50. However, your best bet is to consider which version(s) of SQL Server you'll support and concentrate on those. Will you be prepping for the future? Get the 2016 eval (and run in a VM if possible). Supporting an existing install - get that version and the appropriate tools.

Answer (score 1):

The BI tools for VS 2015 are available for at no cost and work with any SKU of Visual Studio 2015 -- Express, Community, Enterprise, all of 'em.  In fact, if you don't have Visual Studio 2015 installed on your machine, then the installer for the BI tools will install VS2015 for you.  You can download the SSDT tools for BI development here by clicking on the Latest SSDT Preview for Visual Studio 2015: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: it seems the SQL Server has been installed on my machine along with the SSDT\Visual Studio, but I found SSMS is not there. Could you please advise ? Thanks a lot +1

Comment: SSMS can be downloaded from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx